# Dynamic SQL Query for jasper report

Tags: sql, jframe, jasper-reports

i have create a JFrame in netbeans IDE user want to select condition for SQL query on JFrame and according to that dynamic query jasper report should be generate. Please Help me out

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Dynamic Reports](http://dynamicjasper.com/). It is a Jasper Reports based library which enables you to design a report directly from your source code, thus being more flexible to such requirements than using a report designing tool.

1. [Overview](http://www.dynamicreports.org/)
2. [Example](http://www.packtpub.com/article/creating-dynamic-reports-from-databases-jasperreports-3.5)